# Will RADEON R7 240 help linux box with youtube video performance

Tags: linux, video, graphics-card, youtube

I have Acer Aspire XC100 with RAM upgraded to 8 GB running Linux (Ubuntu). I am using the system as a home entertainment system to listen to music etc. The problem is, the system doesn't seem to have enough power to run Youtube videos in full screen mode. Whenever I go full screen, the video starts to get out of sync with audio. This happens even if the video is already loaded up, so it is not an internet connection problem.

Question: Would installing a basic video card, such as RADEON R7 240, improve Youtube video performance?

Comment: I suspect the issue is with flash more than anything else. I can run youtube fine on a 7 year old system with an onboard graphics card and 1gb of ram on windows. I've had issues with flash and linux in the past. I'd give the html5 player a shot https://www.youtube.com/html5

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I have also found Ubuntu to be a sluggish choice in Linux distros. Add to that the sometimes spotty gpu support in Linux for certain chips... But a newer card may help if only to get better drivers if there are some for that card.

Answer (score 0):

No, adding a GPU will not save you. Your system has, if I guess the right version of your hardware, an AMD E1-1200 1.4 GHz APU powering it. Like most of the E series of APUs, this machine actually already has a significant GPU (Radeon HD 7310) embedded in it. However, your CPU side is *severely* lacking in performance, with only two cores operating at 1.4ghz each. Because HTML5 video from YouTube can be relatively CPU intensive, I suspect your CPU's performance is at fault, not your GPU's.

The answer is most likely to switch from default HTML5 video encoding to Flash; or possibly to update/switch your GPU drivers so that if you are using GPU-accelerated video encoding already, your GPU will be better utilized. Fglrx may provide superior performance here compared with Gallium; it's definitely something to try.

Unfortunately, your APU is BGA-soldered to your motherboard, so there's no way to just improve your hardware. If upgrading becomes necessary, it would make sense for you to take a look at AMD's socket AM1 or Intel's embedded Celeron/Pentium options since Haswell; either of these approaches would yield a similarly efficient and cheap machine with a considerable increase in performance both on the CPU and GPU side.